# What did Vic take from Dutch's drawer?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, the-shield

In ***The Shield***, season 1, ep 1, detective Dutch comes back to his desk, opens his drawer and notices something has been taken. Dutch immediately questions Vic why did he take his Ding Dong(s)?

What exactly is a Ding Dong(s)?

- I have a feeling it is Dutch's lucky charm as Dutch says he needs it (them) for late night interrogation. But after I finished watching the entire series the shield, this reference never comes up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ding Dongs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ding_Dong) are a mass-produced snack cake popular in the United States. Presumably Dutch wants them as a snack, since he'll be stuck at the station late into the night due to the interrogation.